# Using a foreach loop to tally up columns, adding sum at the end

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I'm trying to take a CSV, loop through it line by line, field by field, grabbing the values of two columns, perform some simple math, then set the results to a column on the end. I think I've got it down for the most part, but I can't get it to export correctly.

I've tried iterating through, changing the `$field.Value` of the final field and exporting the CSV, but it spits it out wrong. I've also tried outputting each line to a new csv, but can't figure out a way to filter out just the values from the key:value pairs.

```
Import-Csv $csv -Header "SubmissionID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime","TotalDocs","AddnPages","InputFilename","ActualDocs" |
  foreach { 
    foreach ($field in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
      if ($global:count -eq 4) {
        [int]$global:totaldocs = $field.Value
      }
      if ($global:count -eq 5) {
        [int]$global:addnpages = $field.Value
      }
      if ($global:count -eq 7) {
        [int]$global:actualdocs = $global:totaldocs - $global:addnpages
        $global:count = -1
        $field.Value = $global:actualdocs
        Add-Content $outcsv $_.Value
      }
      $global:count = $global:count + 1
    }
  } | Export-Csv $outcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: please post a sample record data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Select-Object` with a calculated property instead:

```
Import-Csv $csv -header "SubmissionID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime","TotalDocs","AddnPages","InputFilename" |
  Select-Object *,@{Name='ActualDocs';Expression={[int]$_.TotalDocs - [int]$_.AddnPages}} |Export-Csv $outcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just neglected to echo the modified records back to the pipeline:

```
$header = 'SubmissionID', 'SubmitterName', ...
Import-Csv $csv -Header $header | ForEach-Object {
  $_.ActualDocs = [int]$_.TotalDocs - [int]$_.AddnPages
  $_     # <-- this line feeds the records back into the pipeline
} | Export-Csv $outcsv -NoType
```

Beware that if you want to write the modified data back to the same file you need to complete reading the file *before* you start writing to it. Run `Import-Csv` in an expression (i.e. put the statement in parentheses) to achieve that:

```
(Import-Csv $csv -Header $header) | ForEach-Object {
  ...
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoType
```

Comment: No, he uses `Add-Content` inline (the `Export-Csv` cmd is completely redundant)

Comment: It was my understanding that the code from his question was just one of several attempts. Not to mention that `Add-Content $outcsv $_.Value` won't work anyway, because the imported CSV records don't have a field named `Value`.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample csv with your columns for a test it looks like this

```
 "1","John","01/31/2017","13:35:54","5","1","testfilename",""
 "2","John","01/31/2017","13:35:54","3","1","testfilename",""
```

I would lose the double looping and work with the current object as an object rather than your multi-dimensional array approach like the example below.

```
 $csv = '.\so.csv'
 ## Remove ActualDocs from the header we will add it later
 import-csv $csv -header "SubmissionID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime","TotalDocs","AddnPages","InputFilename" | foreach-object {
     ## Set current object to a veriable to make it nice to play with
     $RecordObject = $_
     ## Set used column values to a variables
     $TotalDocs = $RecordObject.TotalDocs
     $AddnPages = $RecordObject.AddnPages
     ## perform math
     $ActualDocs = $TotalDocs - $AddnPages
     ## Add ActualDocs column to record object
     $RecordObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ActualDocs' -Value $ActualDocs
     ## output record object for it to get exported via the pipeline to the csv file.
     $RecordObject
 } | export-csv $outcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

A slimmed down version of the above would work the with the current object (`$_`) in the `foreach-object` loop directly like the below example.

```
 ## a slimed down version of the above
 ## Remove ActualDocs from the header we will add it later
 import-csv $csv -header "SubmissionID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime","TotalDocs","AddnPages","InputFilename" | foreach-object {
     ## perform math
     $ActualDocs = $_.TotalDocs - $_.AddnPages
     ## Add ActualDocs column to record object
     $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'ActualDocs' -Value $ActualDocs
     ## Output object
     $_
 } | export-csv $outcsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Both example would create an output csv that look like this:

```
 "SubmissionID","SubmitterName","JobDate","JobTime","TotalDocs","AddnPages","InputFilename","ActualDocs"
 "1","John","01/31/2017","13:35:54","5","1","testfilename","4"
 "2","John","01/31/2017","13:35:54","3","1","testfilename","2"
```